# How do I get my door to shut and latch?

Tags: doors

An interior door will close on its own. I tried to bend the pin and that didn’t help. I then put some thin cardboard behind the bottom hinge and that solved it. However, now the door doesn’t clear the strike plate and won’t shut.

Any suggestion on what I can do to have the door stay open but properly close?

Comment: Wait, won't shut, or won't latch?

Comment: It won’t shut because the door is now pushed out a little too much after adjusting the bottom hinge. Otherwise, it would latch just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the cardboard that caused the issue.

To get the door to stop closing by itself you want to increase the friction between a hinge's knuckles and its pin. Disassemble a hinge from the door and remove its pin. The hinge knuckles are typically constructed by bending a piece of the hinge leaf into the knuckle's cylinder shape to receive the pin. To increase the friction you want to deform the hinge knuckles into tighter cylinders so that spring pressure between the knuckles and the pin will generate more friction.

Just lay both leaves down on a flat, hard surface and whack their knuckles with a hammer to tighten the cylinders. The hinge pins are tapered, so you only want to tighten the top knuckle from each leaf. Because the tapered pin already fits tightest in the hinge's topmost knuckle, you may get sufficient friction by just whacking the knuckle from immediately below the hinge's topmost knuckle. Escalate from weaker blows to striking harder so that you can still get the pin in and so that you don't create too much friction.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. move the lock in the door (difficult)
   OR
2. move the strike plate a small amount (usually easier). If moving is not possible then filing the edge of the strike plate can also work. If the old holes are an issue they can be filled with a glued dowel or matchsticks then the holes re-drilled.